# Pre build es6 npm modules with webpack in production config with uglifyjs

Tags: javascript, npm, ecmascript-6, webpack, uglifyjs

In production, I use webpack config with UglifyJsPlugin.
As you know there are some npm modules with es6 syntaxes. During deploy on production I am getting error:

> ERROR in bundle.js from UglifyJs Unexpected token name «i», expected
>   punc «;» [./~/joi/lib/index.js:167,0]

This is because joi module uses es6 syntax (for (let i in etc..)), but uglify can't handle it.
I've solved problem, precompile several modules (only who use es6) with babel-cli util

```
babel src lib
```

and replace old folder with new one. But it is noncense =). How can I handle array of node modules (not all!, only specified) with webpack config? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is only some harmony support on the harmony branch of uglifyjs (which is still under development and not ready for production). As for UglifyJS v2.0...2.6.2 there is only support for pre-harmony/pre-es6 code.

Comment: It is not uglifyjs problem, it is webpack config problem, I wrote how can resolve it, but I want to know how to do it more automatically. Thank you for response.

Comment: I was able to use webpack and uglifyjs with ES6/ES2015 code using this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40825182/882912