# webpack -p fails to uglify es2015 code

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

The webpack -p cli command fails to uglify es2015 code

package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.13.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.13.2"
  }
```

webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

var config = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    devtool: "source-map",
    output: {
        path: '../Scripts',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                },
                include: ["./src"],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    }
}

module.exports = config;
```

Error when running `webpack -p`

```
ERROR in bundle.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected character '`' [./src/LineEndRenderer.js:33,0]
```

(es2015 template string use)

Running `webpack -d` works fine.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the exact same issue (`"webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.21"`)

Comment: No, not yet :( I got some time before release so I'm just continuing with -d for the time being

Answer (score 1):

A user (fulls1z3) at github came up with a [solution](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/448) that does not require babel (see post from 11/26/2016):

Here is a copy:

> webpack#2 users, I'm hereby trying to help by providing detailed instructions to use the Harmony branch of UglifyJs2 with webpack:
>
> - Fork webpack,
> - On that fork, delete all branches except master,
> - Clone master branch to a local folder,
> - On the local folder, delete all files,
> - Commit the empty local folder,
> - Download the latest release (ex: v2.1.0-beta.27 at the moment)
> - Extract contents of zip file to the local folder,
> - On the local folder, edit forked package.json, change
>     `"uglify-js": "git+https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2.git#harmony"`
>     to point UglifyJs2 (harmony branch) dependency to that branch.
> - Commit changes,
> - Finally, point webpack in your package.json to your custom fork:
>     `"webpack": "[USERNAME]/webpack#master"`
>
> OR,
>
> - Point webpack in your package.json to [fulls1z3/webpack](https://github.com/fulls1z3/webpack) (ES6/ES2015 friendly webpack fork):
>     `"webpack": "fulls1z3/webpack#v2.1.0-beta.27-harmony"`

I was using webpack globally, so I had to run this too:

> npm install yargs supports-color enhanced-resolve interpret tapable webpack-sources source-map uglify-js object-assign async loader-runner acorn watchpack mkdirp ajv ajv-keywords node-libs-browser -g

Then I replaced my global `webpack` npm folder with `webpack-2.1.0-beta.27-harmony.zip` from https://github.com/fulls1z3/webpack/releases

Lastly, I replaced my global `uglify-js` npm folder with `UglifyJS2-harmony.zip` from https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/tree/harmony

Comment: that is insane :dizzy_face:

Comment: Unless UglifyJs will have harmony support, we'll keep suffering from it. I agree, forking all entire webpack is not a reliable solution. On the other hand, bebraw just published [uglifyjs-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin) plugin so that you can use/configure UglifyJs decoupled from webpack.